# phpbb issue: Sorry but this board is currently unavailable

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am new to phpbb. Just installed now, but now I get this "**Sorry but this board is currently unavailable.**" on each link.
What should I do now?

Comment: Not a question for stackoverflow. Try ServerFault instead

Comment: I am doing it on local. what I have to do for local server?

Comment: Still not a question for stackoverflow

Comment: Oh.. do you have a suggestion or some helping words for me?

Answer (score 21):

Delete or rename your `/install` directory on the server.

Comment: Superb. If there is any way to promote this answer it would be great. I have wasted 2 hours and only just came up with the right phrase to get this answer to appear. 2 hours pulling my hair out and 20 seconds to cure. Thanks.